# Convergence of iterated stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-matrices

It is well-known that for a stochastic aperiodic matrix $M$,
the sequence $(M^n)_n$ converges.

Here I would like to a have a more precise analysis. Consider now a sequence of stochastic matrices $(M_n)_n$, converging to $M$. We even assume that there exists $0 < \alpha < 1$ such that for all $n$, we have $||M_n - M|| \le \alpha^n$.
Is it true that $||M_n^n - M^n||$ converges to $0$?

Comment: @Rodrigo, you are flooding the front page with old questions.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is about *matrices* (finite dimension) there is a simple proof. Suppose your matrices are $N\times N$. The key is to note that *any* column stochastic matrix has norm *one* as a map on $\mathbb{R}^N$  *with the $\ell^1$ norm* ($\|(v_1,\ldots,v_N)^T\|_{\ell^1} = \sum_{j=1}^N |v_j|$). Then, since
$$M_n^n -M^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} M_n^k (M_n - M ) M^k$$
and any power of a column stochastic matrix is column stochastic, we obtain
$$\|M_n^n -M^n\|_{\ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^1} \ \le \ n \|M_n -M\|_{\ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^1}.$$
If you were asking about the $\ell^1$ to $\ell^1$ norm, this would answer your question. (Note that this works even for infinite stochastic matrices.)

Probably you were asking about the operator norm when we take the Euclidean ($\ell^2$) norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$.  However, all norms are equivalent in finite dimensions. Explicitly,
$$ \|\vec{v}\|_{\ell^2} \le \|\vec{v}\|_{\ell^1} \le \sqrt{N} \|\vec{v}\|_{\ell^2}$$
and so
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \| M \|_{\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2} \le \|M\|_{\ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^1} \le \sqrt{N} \|M\|_{\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2} $$
for any matrix $M$. Thus
$$\|M_n^n -M^n\|_{\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2} \ \le \ N n \alpha^n,$$
which goes to zero as you would like.

Comment: Doesn't this answer a different question? I thought, the OP asked about the convergence of $\|M_n^n-M_n\|$ to zero...

Comment: Thank you.  There were several missing exponents.  The argument shows that $\|M_n^n -M^n\|$ converges to zero provided $\|M_n -M\|$ converges to zero faster than $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 3 of

"Non-negative Matrices and Markov Chains" by E. Seneta, Springer, reprint 2006,

for general non-negative matrices and chapter 4 (especially section 4.3 ff. for the general case) for stochastic matrices seem to be relevant here.

As you have a bound of the form $||M_n - M|| \leq \alpha^n$, where $\alpha \ < 1$, you can probably follow the reasoning beginning on p. 92 there to show, that $M$ has the form $pe^t$ (assuming column stochastic matrices), where $p$ is a probability vector, while $e = (1, \ldots,1)^t$. In that case you find $M^n \ = \ M$.

For all sufficiently large n you can then try to proceed as follows:

As the $M_n$ converge to $M$, their eigenvalue structure will allow to show that $((M_n)^{(n)})^t$ converges to some $\hat{M_n}$ for fixed $n$, and $||((M_n)^n)^t - \hat{M_n}||$ can be bounded in terms of $||((M_n))^t - \hat{M_n}||$.

$||\hat{M_n} - M||$ will be close to zero, maybe under certain extra conditions, because the $M_n$ converge to $M$. 
The necessary concepts (asymptotic homogenity etc.) seem to be in Seneta.

Comment: I don't get the first line of your answer. Why the $n^{th}$ powers of the matrices $M_n$ would form a subsequence? It seems to be plain wrong, for instance for $1\times 1$ size, the constant sequence $1/2$ converges to $M=1/2$, but $1/2^n\to 0$ and $M\neq 0$.

Comment: @Denis: You are correct of course, a silly mistake of mine. I have edited accordingly. Seneta's book will still be of help here, I suppose.